# Live to local development - redirecting to live site

Tags: magento-1.6, development, localhost

I'm new to Magento (using 1.6.1) and I'm getting very frustrated with it!

Whenever I type my virtual host url into the browser "http://website" it goes straight to the live site.

I've googled the problem over and over to no avail unfortunately.

I've tried:

- changing the secure and unsecure paths in `core_config` to point to http://website
- clearing out everything from `var/cache`
- checking `local.xml` to make sure it was accessing the correct DB
- checking `.htaccess` to make sure there wasn't a redirect in there.

I've looked at similar or the same questions on here and I can't seem to find my solution!

Please let me know if I have missed any key information out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 2 questions for you: 1) Is your virtual host local and does it have the same domain as the live host? -- Be sure your local host file has the local IP for the domain, and/or change the domain altogether. 2) Are you only changing the un/secure domains in the db and not in the admin config? -- Be sure to check the secure/unsecure settings in `System > Configuration > General > Web`, or it will continually overwrite your changes in the db.

Comment: Clear everything from `var/session` as well because base_urls are stored in user sessions.  Don't forget to clear cookies, just to be safe!

Comment: turns out changing it to "http://website.local" worked!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I solved it after setting permissions to folders.I set permission using below command and it worked.In my case `root` is the admin user. Please update command accordingly.

```
sudo chown -R root:root .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \; && sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```